# What is The default JSON specification used in RoR response?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using RoR for a couple of time. But after read many json specification for example [jsonapi.org](http://jsonapi.org/examples/) and [json-schema.org](http://json-schema.org/examples.html) I have the next question: What is the default JSON specification used in RoR ?

Because when you render a json in RoR you get this for example:

```
post: {
 id: 1,
 title: 'Stackoverflow rised 1 billion of alien money',
 description: 'blablabla'
}
```

Is it a good practice if I used the default response in RoR when I'm creating an API ?

Comment: There is no  default JSON specification in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: I a best practice if I build an API without a json specification ?

Comment: @Зелёный Nonono. Programmers.SE is only about software engineering *concepts*. Questions about using a specific API are not well received there, and will be quickly downvoted, closed, and deleted. Please read their [on-topic help center page](https://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: okey, my bad, but i thinking it's about API design. Is an API design about software engineering concepts?

Comment: @Зелёный You may have a point there. I read the question as the concrete programming problem “What is the default behaviour of RoR for JSON responses?”, not as the conceptual design question “When designing an API, is it OK to rely on framework conventions and default behaviour?”. Those two are very different questions.

Comment: that's make sense, thx for clarify  @amon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One specific thing that may or may not be helpful...

One thing that bothers me about the default rendering of JSON w/ Rails is that it leaves the key names unquoted when serializing a Hash, which is (technically) not valid JSON. The way to fix this is to add

```
ActiveSupport::JSON.unquote_hash_key_identifiers = false
```

to a configuration file like environment.rb.  Once you've done that, serializing

```
my_hash = { post: { id: 1, title: 'Stackoverflow rised 1 billion of alien money', description: 'blablabla' } }
```

to JSON would change to

```
post: {
  "id": 1,
  "title": 'Stackoverflow rised 1 billion of alien money',
  "description": 'blablabla'
}
```

vs. what you have above without the quotes.